Rsync repeated copying with --checksum keeps finding differences
When I use the command
rsync -avhc "/mnt/remotes/remote_disk_dir/" "/mnt/user/local_disk_dir" 

repeatedly, rsync seemingly keeps finding differences based on the checksum and therefore overwrites a few files. Normally if no differences are found, the output would be something like:
sending incremental file list
sent 23 bytes  received 130 bytes  2.67M bytes/sec
total size is 61.88G  speedup is 75.66

I keep getting outputs like this:
sending incremental file list
file1.mp4
file7.mp4
file45.mp4
file68.mp4
sent 1.64G bytes  received 73 bytes  2.62M bytes/sec
total size is 61.88G  speedup is 31.94

It is not the same files that is overwritten each time. The total size is about 60 GB with individual file sizes either around 10 MB or 500 MB. I have run the command 10 times and it still happens.
I run the command from the terminal in Unraid 6.12.13 and the remote share is on a Windows 10 machine.
Why does this happen?
I am a complete beginner when it comes to Linux and command line.

add -i and rsync will tell you what caused each file to be updated.  If there are multiple differences, the field with the -i output will show them.  Perhaps it's not the checksum that's doing it.

With -i added to the command I get the output >fc........ file7.mp4 for a handful of files. If I understand correctly > means that the file is being transferred to the local host (the Unraid machine), f tells me it's a file c means that a local change is occurring and A . means that the item is not being updated (though it might have attributes that are being modified). So does this mean that something keeps changing at the host side?

The second and third run with -i added did not result in any changes so the problem seems to have fixed itself. This is very weird. I ran the command 10 times before posting and each time a random handful of files were overwritten. Any ideas what happened?

You were right, the first column's f indicates the listed item is a file (rather than a directory or link, device file, etc.), and the second column's c shows the file checksum was different.  The other columns would have things like 't' for timestamp, 's' for size, u, for user ownership, g for group ownership, and some others I don't recall at the moment.  Sounds like something was still updating the source files for a while.  Since it's mounted from a remote server, I would look at whatever creates those files to learn what was happening.
